# Adding list of check boxes in a single widget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt Creator 2.0.1 (Qt 4.7). I need a widget which can hold multiple check boxes vertically. The check boxes will be added to the widget dynamically upon user interaction with other UI element. The widget will have fixed width and height so if there are too many check boxes, a vertical scroll bar should appear.

What I want is, imagine a QListWidget, where the list items can be check boxes.

Which widget will allow me to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well you could indeed use a [`QListWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qlistwidgetitem.html) with checkable items (see [`void QListWidgetItem::setFlags`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qlistwidgetitem.html#setFlags), or use a [`QScrollArea`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qscrollarea.html) containing a `QWidget` where you would dynamically add [`QCheckBoxes`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qcheckbox.html). The choice is up to you!

Answer (score 13):

Use QListWidget for the area.

```
QStringList  itemLabels= getLabels();

QStringListIterator it(itemLabels);
while (it.hasNext())
{
      QListWidgetItem *listItem = new QListWidgetItem(it.next(),listWidget);
      listItem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
      ui->listWidget->addItem(listItem);
}
```

this will automatically make all the elements checkable and when the list increases it will enable scrolling.

Comment: Moreover, if you construct QListWidgetItem with the list widget as its parent widget, it is not necessary to add the item to the list.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to QListWidget is a QScrollArea with a widget inside, which has a QVBoxLayout. To that layout, you can add QCheckboxes dynamically. You must call updateGeometry() after adding a new widget, otherwise the UI might not update if already visible.